# Stripe - Passing in parameter "Amount" from another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, parameters

So I am implementing the checkout.js Stripe script to pay for a "booking". I have the following in booking/show.html.erb

```
  <center>
  <b>Address:</b>
  <%= @booking.address %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Catering:</b>
  <%= @booking.catering.foodtype %>
  <b>$</b>
    <%= @booking.catering.cost %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Customer:</b>

  <%= @booking.customer.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Eventtype:</b>
  <%= @booking.eventtype %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Finishdatetime:</b>
  <%= @booking.finishdatetime %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Marquee:</b>

   <%= @booking.marquee.name%>
   <b>$</b>
  <%= @booking.marquee.cost%>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Musician:</b>
  <%= @booking.musician.name %>
  <b>$</b>
  <%= @booking.musician.cost %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Size:</b>
  <%= @booking.size %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Startdatetime:</b>
  <%= @booking.startdatetime %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Toilet:</b>
  <%= @booking.toilet.name %>
  <b>$</b>
   <%= @booking.toilet.cost %>
</p>

<p>
 <b>TOTAL COST:</b>
 <%=  @totalcost = @booking.toilet.cost + @booking.musician.cost + @booking.catering.cost  + @booking.marquee.cost %>

 </p>


 <p>
<a href="#" onclick="window.print();return false;">Print this invoice</a>
</p> 

<a href="http://localhost:3000/charges/new">Pay</a>

</center>
```

However in my charges controller, the amount is hard coded into the create method, like so

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController

    def new
    end

    def create
      # Amount in cents
      @amount = 500

      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :email => params[:email],
        :card  => params[:stripeToken]
      )

      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :customer    => customer.id,
        :amount      => @amount,
        :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
        :currency    => 'eur'
      )

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      redirect_to charges_path
    end
end
```

I want to have it so that when I click "Pay" at the bottom of my show it brings me to the charges/new page where the amount is passed over. I'm not sure how to do this as the charges create method won't know for which booking instance to take the params from because it is just a direct href link to the charges/new page.

It is probably quite complicated but if someone could steer me in the right direction that would be great!

Comment: You can pass booking _id as query parameter like `"http://localhost:3000/charges/new?booking_id=#{@booking.id}"` then pass it in post parameters to create method

Comment: @PramodShinde That seems like it would work. Could you put it into its' respective classes please?

Comment: I would suggest you use a nested model here:
````http://localhost:3000/bookings/{booking.id}/charges/new````

Answer (score 0):

You can call your `create`controller with an AJAX request with the amount in the parameters.
Then in your controller you can do for example:

```
@amount = params['amount']
```

You should check the Stripe guide where everything is explain :
https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/guides/rails

As well, there is so many ways to do it and I propose you a solution that maybe is not the better.

Cheers,

Comment: This is probably a bad idea. The user can alter the url and change the amount charged. The comment by @Pramod Shinde is the way to go